# Merge two XML files in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

There are some posts about this topic, but I wasn't able to figure out how to solve my problem.

I have two XML files:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <some>
      <value></value>
    </some>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <more>
      <data></data>
    </more>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

And:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <some_other>
      <value></value>
    </some_other>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

I want to generate an XML document that looks like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <some>
      <value></value>
    </some>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <more>
      <data></data>
    </more>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <some_other>
      <value></value>
    </some_other>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Every node `<Product>` should be merged into `<Products>`.

I tried to create a new document using:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML("<Products></Products>")
nodes = files.map { |xml| Nokogiri::XML(xml).xpath("//Product") }
set = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(doc, nodes)
```

but this throws an error: `ArgumentError: node must be a Nokogiri::XML::Node or Nokogiri::XML::Namespace`.

I think I don't understand `NodeSet`, but I can't figure out how to merge these two XML files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample code won't generate what you want because you're throwing away your `some` and `more` nodes when you do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML("<Products></Products>")
```

Instead of creating an empty DOM, you need to piggyback on the original and simply append the new nodes to it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml1 = '<Products>
  <Product>
    <some>
      <value></value>
    </some>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <more>
      <data></data>
    </more>
  </Product>
</Products>
'

xml2 = '<Products>
  <Product>
    <some_other>
      <value></value>
    </some_other>
  </Product>
</Products>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml1)
```

Find the new `Product` nodes to be added:

```
new_products = Nokogiri::XML(xml2).search('Product')
```

Append them to the original document as added children of `Products`:

```
doc.at('Products').add_child(new_products)
```

This results in the DOM in `doc` looking like:

```
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <Products>
# >>   <Product>
# >>     <some>
# >>       <value/>
# >>     </some>
# >>   </Product>
# >>   <Product>
# >>     <more>
# >>       <data/>
# >>     </more>
# >>   </Product>
# >> <Product>
# >>     <some_other>
# >>       <value/>
# >>     </some_other>
# >>   </Product></Products>
```

Comment: Well, I'm not adverse to letting you do a lot of work to figure things out, since that's what I've had to do, but after looking at several related questions here on SO I found none that was the exact thing you wanted to do so I figured I'd better help document the process. :-) I'm glad it helped though. XML/HTML manipulation can be confusing but it's really easy once you learn the tricks and how Nokogiri can help.